# cannot login to whatsapp-web.js by puppeteer error

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, whatsapp

I have been using whatsapp-web.js for long time, but it doesn't want to work anymore, I think it is not a error of my own, could you please help me?, it worked for many days, this happens when I try to log in.

```
throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + helper_js_1.helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
                  ^

Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:14:123
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\Users\54112\Downloads\postall-bot2\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\Users\54112\Downloads\postall-bot2\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
    at async Client.initialize (C:\Users\54112\Downloads\postall-bot2\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\src\Client.js:267:9)
```

I don't know very much about puppeteers, so I couldn't find a solution by my self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/src/util/Injected.js` at line 17 change:

```
window.Store.GroupMetadata = window.mR.findModule((module) => module.default && module.default.handlePendingInvite)[0].default;
```

To:

```
window.Store.GroupMetadata = window.mR.findModule('GroupMetadata')[0].default.GroupMetadata;
```

Solutions of commons issues are in the official github repo: https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/1795